# VBA Excel code followhyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel, containing cell **A1** as `c:\user\download` and cell **A2** contains `c:\user` and cell **A3** contains `c:\`.

Where I used the coding as follows :

```
Sub opendfolder()
    Dim myfolder As String, nextfolder as string, nextfolder1 as string

    myfolder = Range("a1").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink myfolder

    nextfolder = range("a2").value
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink nextfolder

    nextfolder1 = range("a3").value
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink nextfolder1
End Sub
```

But my problem is now is that VBA code should execute to check first the cell **A1**, if it got error then goto cell **A2** and so on ...

**And one more** if VBA code able to execute at cell **A1** level only then there is no need to execute next cells **A2** or **A3**. Now the coding which I have written is executing all the three.

Can you help me writing the code which will be execute at cell **A1**, if **A1** fails then go to **A2**. if cell **A2** is able to execute successfully then it should not execute to code at cell **A3**. The code should stop at cell **A2**.

If fails at **A2** cell, then it should try for cell **A3**.

Please help me, I was not able to get the logic how to write a code in the above scenario.

Comment: seriously ? asap ?

Comment: you should check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80538/how-to-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to figure out how to catch an error. I guess you can figure out how to arrange the `if` statements yourself.

```
On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "c:\aaa"
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "there was an error"
        'an error occured, try next link
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
```